# Применение нескольких эффектов к фото UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, sdk

Есть возможность применения фильтров к картинке, но могу применить только 1 фильтр, используется lumia imaging sdk. При разработке на Win 8.1 использовал массив с фильтрами и они сразу все применялись, здесь так не получается, есть какой-нибудь способ применить сразу несколько фильтров?

Код для применения эффекта:

```
  public async Task<bool> ApplyEffectAsync(StorageFile file)
    {
        WriteableBitmap temp = new WriteableBitmap(1280, 720);

            temp = new WriteableBitmap(1280, 720);
            FileStream = await File.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            temp.SetSource(FileStream);
            OriginalPicture = temp;
            FileStream.Seek(0);
            original.Invalidate();
            ((IImageConsumer) Effect).Source = new RandomAccessStreamImageSource(FileStream);
            M_renderer = new WriteableBitmapRenderer((IImageProvider)Effect, original);
            FilteringPicture = await M_renderer.RenderAsync();
            filtering.Invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `Effect.Source` необходимо передавать уже отфильтрованное ранее изображение, а не считывать его из `FileStream`

Answer (score 1):

Для применения эффектов вы можете использовать библиотеку [Win2D](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm)
Пример можете найти [здесь](https://www.eternalcoding.com/?p=1911)
Для совмещения нескольких эффектов там можно использовать CompositeEffect
Пример:

```
var myTextBitmap = new CanvasRenderTarget(sender, 300, 100);
using (var ds = myTextBitmap.CreateDrawingSession())
{
  ds.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
  ds.DrawText("Неоновый текст!", 0, 0, Colors.White, new CanvasTextFormat
  {
      FontSize = 24,
      FontWeight = Windows.UI.Text.FontWeights.Bold
  });
}

var effectGraph = new CompositeEffect();
effectGraph.Mode = CanvasComposite.Add;

effectGraph.Sources.Add(new ColorMatrixEffect
{
  Source = new GaussianBlurEffect
  {
      Source = new MorphologyEffect
      {
          Source = myTextBitmap,
          Mode = MorphologyEffectMode.Dilate,
          Width = 7,
          Height = 4
      },
      BlurAmount = 3f
  },
  ColorMatrix = new Matrix5x4
  {
      M11 = 0f, M12 = 0f, M13 = 0f, M14 = 0f,
      M21 = 0f, M22 = 0f, M23 = 0f, M24 = 0f,
      M31 = 0f, M32 = 0f, M33 = 0f, M34 = 0f,
      M41 = 0f, M42 = 1f, M43 = 0f, M44 = 1f,
      M51 = 1f, M52 = -0.5f, M53 = 0f, M54 = 0f
  }
});

effectGraph.Sources.Add(myTextBitmap);
args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(effectGraph,100,100);
```

Кроме того можно использовать Lumia Imaging SDK, но как там с несколькими эффектами сказать не могу.

Comment: Я как раз использую lumia sdk

Comment: Ах, простите, проглядел. Но вариант с Win2D, надеюсь вам подкинул.